# Horus Heresy demon-hybrid character, possibly a traitor

Tags: character-identification, warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

I have been listening to the *Horus Heresy* audio books, which is great until you try looking up characters online who have strange-sounding names.

The character I am trying to identify is from the latest book, *The First Wall*. So far he has appeared in one scene, but I am unsure if he has been mentioned before this appearance.

The name, as far as I can get from repeated listening, is something like "Folk Sa Aram". However googling that name has not given any good responses.

He is a hybrid between demon and I think traitor legionary, possibly Iron Warriors. In the story he is met by a tech priest of the Dark Mechanicum in the Lion's Gate spaceport. He then uses the priest to hack into the spaceport code. He also seems to have Superman-type eyes, able to melt through metal.

Has this being been seen in previous books? Either something I have missed or forgotten or possibly a book I haven't read yet (I am simultaneously catching up while also listening to the latest releases).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your transcription was quite close: it's actually **Volk-Sa'ra'am**, formerly known as Iron Warrior Volk, later possessed by the Daemon Sa'ra'am, making him an [Obliterator](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Obliterator).

From the [Lexicanum](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Volk):

> Volk was an Iron Warrior and commander of the 786th Grand Flight during the Horus Heresy.
>
> A skilled Lightning Crow pilot during the Great Crusade Volk established something of a friendship with fellow Luna Wolves pilot Argonis. By the Heresy Volk was fighting a bitter war on Krade against a renewed loyalist offensive led by the Ultramarines. The situation was interrupted by Argonis, who arrived as an emissary of Horus ordering Perturabo to find Angron and muster at Ullanor for the drive on Terra. Volk was disheartened to see a planet he had fought so bitterly for abandoned, and led a daring raid into the loyalist lands the night before they were due to evacuate in order to bleed the enemy one last time.
>
> Due to his close relationship with Argonis, Perturabo kept Volk by his side during their journey to find Angron. On Sarum, the group met with the Daemon Sa'ra'am which revealed that Angron was on the world of Deluge. However Sa'ra'am broke free of its bindings and possessed the body of Volk, transforming him into the first Obliterator. It's unknown if any essence of Volk survived this process, but the creature went on to fight alongside Perturabo, Forrix, and Argonis on Deluge against Angron and his crazed World Eaters. Volk survived the battle of Deluge and was brought to the muster on Ullanor.
>
> During the Siege of Terra Volk, known *[sic]* known as Volk-Sa'ra'ram *[sic]* , worked with Dark Mechanicum Magos Inar Satarael to introduce a Daemonic computer virus into the systems of the Lion's Gate Spaceport.

He previously appeared in [*Slaves to Darkness*](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Slaves_to_Darkness_(Novel)) (2018).

---

Found with the Google query `"first wall" gav thorpe review hybrid traitor` which returned a transcribed PDF (which I won't link to).

Comment: Great thankyou :) did listen to that book but forgot the name of the marine and demon. The problem of audio books no dramatis persona page

Comment: By the way, if anyone has edit rights on the Lexicanum page (it's locked when I try to), please change _"known known as Volk-Sa'ra'ram"_ to _"now known as Volk-Sa'ra'am"_ (spelling error in the "now" and extra `r` in the name). Cheers